# Why do subnodes act like static attribute?

Tags: python, tree, python-3.5

I tried to implement a tree data structure in Python. This is what I've ended up so far:

```
class Node:
    """
    This class implements a node in a tree.

    # Arguments #
    metadata:dict=dict()    |   A dict to store metadata.
    subnodes:tuple=tuple()  |   A tuple to define subnodes.
    """

    def __init__(self, metadata={"label": None, "content": None, "description": None}, subnodes=list()):
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.subnodes = subnodes

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{label}] {content}".format(
            label=str(self["label"]),
            content=str(self["content"])
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}>".format(str(self))

    def __len__(self):
        count = len(self.subnodes)

        for n in self.subnodes:
            print(n)
            count+=len(n.subnodes)

        return count

    def __contains__(self, o):
        # check if in subnodes of self
        if o in self.subnodes:
            return True

        # check if in subnodes (recursive)
        for n in self.subnodes:
            if o in n:
                return True

        return False

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.metadata[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.metadata[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.metadata[key]

    def __lt__(self, o):
        return self in o

    def __gt__(self, o):
        return o in self

    def append(self, o:"Node"):
        """
        Appends an object as children.

        # Arguments #
        o:Node  |   Node object.
        """

        self.subnodes.append(o)

    def insert(self, i:int, o:"Node"):
        """
        Inserts an object to given index.

        # Arguments #
        i:int   |   Index
        o:Node  |   Node object
        """

        self.subnodes.insert(i, o)

    def remove(self, o:"Node"):
        """
        Removes an object from subnodes.

        # Arguments #
        o:Node  |   Node object
        """

        self.subnodes.remove(o)

    def is_leafnode(self):
        """
        Is this node a leaf node?
        """

        return len(self) == 0

    def search(self, **query):
        """
        Searches tree with metadata.

        **query:dict    |   Searching query.
        """

        return [d for d in self.metadata if all(d.get(k, object()) == v for k, v in query.items())]
```

I add subnodes by `append` function of a `Node` object. However, `subnodes` attribute acts as if it was a static attribute.

What I expect is:

[image]

However, `subnodes` attribute of all objects returns:

[image]

#### Manual Test

I have tested it by hand. I have 6 `Node` objects as below:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
- f

I wanted to achieve a structure as I demonstrated above. So I made:

```
a.append(b) # a => b
a.append(c) # a => c

b.append(d) # b => d
b.append(e) # b => e

c.append(f) # c => f
```

However, when I call `subnodes` attribute of any `Node` object:

```
a.subnodes # [<[b] None>, <[c] None>, <[d] None>, <[e] None>, <[f] None>]
b.subnodes # [<[b] None>, <[c] None>, <[d] None>, <[e] None>, <[f] None>]
# ...
# rest is the same
```

---

### Environment

- Python 3.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be caused by the [Default Parameter Value](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) issue.

What this means is that the default parameter `subnodes=list()` in the definition `__init__` is evaluated exactly one time, during the creation of the class `Node`. From this point onward, the same mutable object will be used as the default value whenever you instantiate a new object. And as this is a mutable object, whenever you append something to `self.subnodes`, you're actually modifying the default value. There is a quite detailed discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941).

Basically, the rule in Python is to *never* use mutable data types as default argument values. Instead, use `None`, and explicitly assign the default values like so:

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, metadata={"label": None, "content": None, "description": None}, subnodes=None):
      self.metadata = metadata
      if subnodes is None:
          self.subnodes = []
      else:
          self.subnodes = subnodes
```

Comment: Strange, I didn't know that. Thanks, that solved problem. :)